# Chrome extension, how to ignore node_modules to load faster in development

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension and I'm relying on some NPM modules. While I do have webpack to help packaging stuff for production environment, it seems that Chrome takes the entire directory into account when loading my unpacked extension during development, which is roughly `340M`! This also makes debugging and testing a drag because click open the Chrome extension pop up takes 3 ~ 5 seconds.

I've been googling whether there is an option in the `manifest.json` file but nothing helpful came up. Did I miss something obvious?

If I hadn't, what is the recommended workflow? Should I output everything into a `/dist` folder and have my `manifest.json` file there?

Comment: I build my extension with webpack too. Webpack output is set to `/dist` directory. `manifest.json` also is copied in `/dist` and the extension is loaded from `/dist`. If you still encounter the problem with such setup, if possible, please share your webpack config.

Comment: @Granga that's what I'm trying to do now, I think that set up makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to place `manifest.json` inside your `dist` folder instead of the root of your project:

```
/
|- webpack.config.js
|- package.json
|- node_modules/
+- dist/
     |- manifest.json
     +- contentscript.js
```

There's no way to *exclude* files from a manifest.